# An inequality for matrix norms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequalities, matrix-analysis

Working on a problem in combinatorics I come up with the following inequality on matrix norms, which I checked it also numerically:

> Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be a real symmetric $n\times n$ matrix with trace equal to zero. If $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ be all of eigenvalues of $A$, then 
>   $$\sum_i |\lambda_i|\geq \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i\neq j} \big\vert  a_{ij}-\frac{a_{ii}+a_{jj}}{2}\big\vert.$$

I have a very long combinatorial proof for this inequality, but I'm curious if there is a more straightforward proof. Thanks!

Comment: Wlog we may suppose that $a_{ij}=x_i x_j-y_i y_j$ for two orthogonal unit vectors $x, y$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yes.And the whole fight is for $-1$ in $n-1$; if we had the factor $1/n$ instead, the estimate would be trivial.

Comment: @fedja exactly:)

Comment: Also for $n$ instead $n-1$ it is true without the assumption that trace is equal 0 (and in this case we may assume that $a_{ij}=x_ix_j$).

Comment: For what it's worth, here is an equivalent reformulation. Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite graph. Define $\Lambda(G)$ to be the largest constant $\lambda$ such that $\sum_{(i,j)\in E}(x_i-x_j)^2\ge\lambda \sum_{i\in V}x_i^2$ for all real $x_i$ with $\sum_{i\in V}x_i=0$. We want to show that $\Lambda(G)+\Lambda(G^c)\ge 1$ where $G^c$ is the complement of $G$.

Comment: @fedja: Your equivalent reformulation is actually the source of the question asked by Mostafa. I and Mostafa have an almost long proof for it and we will submit a primary version of the proof on Arxiv, as soon as possible. We are curious to know is there any more straightforward proof based on the reformulation stated in OP? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @fedja: A solution for your equivalent reformulation is here, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.02047. I'm sorry for the delay in sharing the solution. It is pleasant if you tell us your constructive advice about the solution. I have learned a lot from you in MO. Merry Christmas, Dear Fedja.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Could you please explain how rank-2 can be assumed wlog, as you mentioned?

Comment: @DSM Denote $A=\sum \lambda_i P_i$, where $P_i$'s are rank 1 projections onto orthogonal lines; $\sum |\lambda_i|=2L$. Then $A$ is a combination of $P_i-P_j$ with non-negative coefficients which sum up to $L$. If for each matrix $P_i-P_j$ you have such a bound, their combination gives a necessary inequality.